# Integration do not know how to proceed: $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x\cdot(x+1)^\frac14} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Integration 0 to infinity

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x\cdot(x+1)^\frac14}dx$$

How to proceed ?
Answer : $8C+\pi^2$

Procedure wanted

Comment: Try sub $t=\ln(x+1)$. It should simplify in a way.

Comment: I get t* e^(3t/4)/(e^t - 1) now ?

Comment: I don't think you can really calculate an antiderivative for this function. I was not succesfull, and neither is wolfram.

Comment: I agree with 5xum, when trying just the antiderivative, wolfram gives: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+ln%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x*%28x%2B1%29^%281%2F4%29%29

Comment: yea... but that's indefinite ... try a definite integral

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration+0+to+inf++ln%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x*%28x%2B1%29^%281%2F4%29%29

Comment: 8C + pi^2 is answer.. please can u explain how ?

Comment: Do you think there is an approach through contour integration?

Answer (score 4):

First, assume $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

Then:

$\displaystyle \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{24}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

Therefore:
 $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$ (1)

Let $\displaystyle I=\int_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{x (x+1)^\frac14}dx$

Perform change of variable $u=(x+1)^\frac14$:

$\displaystyle I=\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{16x^2\log(x)}{x^4-1}dx$

Therefore:
$\displaystyle I=\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{8\log(x)}{x^2-1}dx+\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{8\log(x)}{x^2+1}dx$

The last integral equals $8G$ where $G$ is the Catalan's constant.

Let $\displaystyle J=\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{8\log(x)}{x^2-1}dx$

Perform change of variable $u=\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$:

$\displaystyle J=\int_0^1 4\log\Big(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\Big)\dfrac{dx}{x}=4\Big(\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)dx}{x}-\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1-x)dx}{x}\Big)$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)dx}{x}=\int_0^1  \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n x^n}{n+1}\Big) dx=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \Big( \int_0^1\dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{n+1}dx  \Big)$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)dx}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^2}$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)dx}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)^2}=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{24}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

Apply (1) :
$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)dx}{x}=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{24}+\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$

$\displaystyle -\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1-x)dx}{x}=\int_0^1 \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n+1}\Big) dx=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \Big(\int_0^1\dfrac{x^n}{n+1}dx  \Big)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}= \dfrac{\pi}{6}$

Therefore:
$J=4 \times \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}+4 \times \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}=\pi^2$

$I=8G+\pi^2$

Answer (score 3):

$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty(x+1)^n\frac{dx}x\iff\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x\cdot(x+1)^\frac14} dx=I'\bigg(-\frac14\bigg)$$

Let $t=\dfrac1{x+1}$ , and recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, then use the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula), *but do not compute its value, since it will be divergent* ! Rather, derive it directly with regard to *n*. The expression of the derivative *will* converge. But it will require knowledge of the [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function), as well as of [generalized harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments). In the end, the entire expression will eventually simplify to the beautiful $\pi^2+8G$, where *G* is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). Hope this helps ! I was also thinking of an alternative, by expanding $\ln(1+x)$ into its well-known [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions), but I just don't see a way around the $\sqrt[4]{1+x}$ in the denominator. Maybe someone else can chime in and shed some more light into this situation, or maybe even develop a better or more elegant approach.

Comment: Nice, ... again ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is awful (at least to me !). I was wondering if a CAS could do it; it did and I am sure that you will enjoy the result $$\frac{G_{3,3}^{3,2}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{3}{4},1 \\
 0,0,0
\end{array}
\right.\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$ in which appears the Meijer G function (I am sure you are happy to know that !). The numerical value of this nice expression is $17.19732915$.

If I may ask, where did you get this monster from ?

**Added to my answer**

Since I produced the above monster, I let it !

If you make a change of variable such that $x+1=e^{4y}$, you have something which is more pleasant. The result of the integral is $8 C+\pi ^2$, $C$ being the Catalan number.

Comment: My friend on my Mathematics FB page gave it to me.. I'll ask if the answer is correct
thoughI think 8C + pi^2 would be the answer.

Comment: also how did u get 8C + pi^2 it is the correct answer... please show procedure

Comment: Isn't this just $\psi^{(1)}(1/4)$ where $\psi^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ [Polygammma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function)? On Wolfram alpha, 
the command [Polygamma[1,1/4]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolyGamma[1%2C1%2F4]) gives us an alternate form for $\psi^{(1)}(1/4) = 8C + \pi^2$ where $C$ is the [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: @achillehui. How did you think about it ?

Comment: Since $\frac{\log(1+x)}{(1+x)^\beta} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\frac{1}{(1+x)^\beta}$, one can obtain the answer by differentiating beta integrals under integral sign.

Answer (score 0):

With $y^4=x+1$, Maple gets the antiderivative
$$
V(y)=2\,\ln  \left( y+i \right) \pi +2\,\ln  \left( y-i \right) \pi -4\,
\ln  \left( 1+y \right) \ln  \left( y \right) -4\,i{\rm Li}_2
 \left( 1-iy \right) +4\,i{\rm Li}_2 \left( 1+iy \right) -4\,{
\rm Li}_2 \left( -y \right) -4\,{\rm Li}_2 \left( 1-y
 \right)
$$
Now $V(0)=-8 \;\mathrm{Catalan} + \pi^2/3$ and $\lim_{y\to\infty} V(y) = 4\pi^2/3$, so subtract to get our answer $8 \;\mathrm{Catalan} + \pi^2$.